# wpf layout with datagrid and expander

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, devexpress

Im having trouble getting my xaml to work the way i want to.

What i want to is this.
My ItemsControl should have a height of 70. The rest of the space should be filled with a DockPanel.
Inside the DockPanel i have a GridControl (DataGrid from DevExpress) that are supposed to fill all empty space. The gridcontrol is docked to top. Below the gridcontrol but still insdie the dockpanel, i have a Expander that have a maxheight of 480, this should be docked to the bottom.

The problem im having is that i can't get the gridcontrol to dynamically change it's height so that it fills all remaining space between the top of the docking panel down to the Expander.

What am i doing wrong?

```
<Grid Background="White">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="70" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<!--#region ItemControl-->
<ItemsControl
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="9"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    IsTabStop="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ToolbarControlViewModel.CommandButtonList}"
    Style="{DynamicResource ActionBarPanel}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        ...
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
<!--#endregion-->

<DockPanel Grid.Row="1">

    <!--#region Listview-->
    <dxg:GridControl
        x:Name="CMGrid"
        DockPanel.Dock="Top"
        Margin="0,0,0,10"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CustomerManagementListViewModel.Customers}"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            ...
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView
                x:Name="CustomerListView"
                AllowBestFit="True"
                FocusedRow="{Binding Path=CustomerManagementListViewModel.SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}"
                IsColumnMenuEnabled="False"
                NavigationStyle="Row"
                ShowGroupPanel="False" 
                AutoWidth="True"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region Controls-->
    <Expander
        MaxHeight="480"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
        Header="{T:Translate Equipment,
                             Format=' {0}:'}"
        IsExpanded="True"
        Style="{StaticResource K2M_Epander_Base}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Expander.Content>
            <Grid>
                ...
            </Grid>
        </Expander.Content>
    </Expander>
    <!--#endregion-->
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Ditch the `DockPanel` all together and apply your Row=1 to the GridControl. That's your culprit.

Comment: So simple! It works, thanks alot! :) If you write it as a answer I'll credit you for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel bad getting points for such a quickie but if the question's going to remain I guess we may as well give some closure for future finders.

So, `DockPanel` has its uses but in this scenario it's your culprit. As a DockPanel nested in a layout as such is basically the equivalent of attaching the `VerticalAlignment="Top"` property to your GridControl. Which interprets as it only consuming the space necessary for it from the top down of the parent row.

By removing the `DockPanel` entirely (since in this scenario it's redundant) and applying the Row declaration directly to the `GridControl` it has the ability to act as a normal child to the parent `Grid` container and will consume the space provided by the Row's `*` declaration.

Glad you got it sorted, got to love the quick 'n easy ones. Cheers :)